# Latency with webGL plugin (webgl-image-filter)

Tags: canvas, webgl

After using a lot of library to allow me to manipulate canvas (glfx, camanJS ...), i found : https://github.com/slub/webgl-image-filter.

It's work well but it's not fast. How can i resolve this problem?

Code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.css">

    <style>
        .slider {
            width: 200px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="slider"></div>
    <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/phoboslab/WebGLImageFilter/e0eee0cd/webgl-image-filter.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script>

        const image = new Image();
        image.crossOrigin = "anonymous";
        image.src = "https://picsum.photos/5000/2688?image=0";

        image.onload = function() {
          try {
            var filter = new WebGLImageFilter();
          }
          catch( err ) {
            console.log(err)
          }

          filter.addFilter('brightness', 0);

          var filteredImage = filter.apply(image);
          document.body.appendChild(filteredImage);

            $( ".slider" ).slider({
                min: 0,
                max: 100,

                slide: function( event, ui ) {
                    filter.addFilter('brightness', ui.value / 1000 );
                    var filteredImage = filter.apply(image);
                    document.body.appendChild(filteredImage);
                }
            })
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Does not look like that library is active: https://github.com/slub/webgl-image-filter/commits/master last commit was Apr 28, 2016, you can try report your issue there, but probably it is no longer maintained

Comment: Also looking at the image you are using: `width="5000" height="2688"`, that will be  the bottleneck on any library, Have you consider reducing the size of that image?

Comment: thanks for your reply but i already reduced the picture to screen size but it's long. I can't reduce more because i would like to add this project in another project. I want to create a project to modify image using contrast, blur etc

Comment: IF what you are looking for is the fastest possible experience you should consider creating a native app

Comment: IF you need something web based, consider doing the "heavy lifting" server side, in the browser show a small preview image and then do all the final processing on the back end.

Comment: thank you, i found that link which works well : http://evanw.github.io/webgl-filter/. I don't know why, i'm going to look. Do you think i should read and understand all code or i can retrieve some parts?

Comment: That project is older than the other in your post: https://github.com/evanw/webgl-filter/commits/master last commit was on Aug 28, 2011

Comment: Also look at the size of the image in that demo: http://evanw.github.io/webgl-filter/samples/mountain.jpg _  _ _ (640 x 479) your original is (5000 x 2688)

Comment: If you want to consider a native app take a look at: https://github.com/GNOME/gimp, in the website they have:  `GIMP is a cross-platform image editor available for GNU/Linux, OS X, Windows and more operating systems`

Comment: Thank's a lot i will go see